# How to store SSE connections?

Tags: node.js, api, http, server, server-sent-events

I'm setting up a Nodejs express server in Firebase. I have a Dashboard page. The user can save items to their dashboard at any time using a Chrome Extension. I want their new saved items to appear regularly on the dashboard.

Busy polling seems straightforward to run with

```
setInterval( () => {
   // async call to api with paging cursor
```

But that seems to be a waste of resources.

I read about Server Side Events and tried to implement them with code. All the SSE examples I've seen look something like this:

```
var clients = {}; // <- Keep a map of attached clients

app.get('/events/', function (req, res) {
    req.socket.setTimeout(Number.MAX_VALUE);
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    });
    res.write('\n');
    (function (clientId) {
    clients[clientId] = res;
    req.on("close", function () {
      delete clients[clientId]
    }); 
    })(++clientId)
});

setInterval(function () {
    var msg = Math.random();
    console.log("Clients: " + Object.keys(clients) + " <- " + msg);
    for (clientId in clients) {
        clients[clientId].write("data: " + msg + "\n\n"); // <- Push a message to a single attached client
    };
}, 2000);
```

Getting the SSE events to work is no problem in the test examples, and it works for my use cases.

However, my concerns:

1. Every express response is stored in memory. 100k users is a lot of memory
2. The API POST method needs access to the clients/responses. A response object can't easily be stored in a DB.
3. Ideally, each request is authenticated with header auth bearer tokens. This does seem to be possible with browser EventSource

How do enterprise level apps actually implement effective SSE?

Comment: I have this exact same question, and haven't been able to find any decent answers

Comment: its been a year, did you guys managed to find solution @stg123

Comment: @PriyathGregory I've been trying to find this out too, I'm about to go forward with an app but I can't seem to believe this is how it's done. Did you guys find out?

Comment: @DarkMakukudo Did you find any solution? I'm stuck too

Comment: @Amon, unfortunately not because we abandoned the project, goodluck!

Comment: @DarkMakukudo It looks like you're just supposed to store the connections in memory, inside an array for example. According to my research